# What does Reformat code do when pushing to Git in PhpStorm and where to set it?

Tags: version-control, formatting, phpstorm, git-commit

I've found that there is a **option to Reformat** code **before commiting** it to Git repository. My idea when I saw this was that I can use **two different formatting** for **myself** and fxp. **team/company**. Is this what is this option suppose to do? If so **where can I specify** the **code formatting** for commiting? And what is the **difference** between **Reformating and Rearranging** code?

[image: PhpStorm git push options]

I've tried my luck in PhpStorm documentation but I've found only where to set code formatting for the local Reformat option.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My idea when I saw this was that I can use two different formatting
>   for myself and fxp. team/company. Is this what is this option suppose
>   to do?

No.
`Reformat code` in **Before commit** is the same as `Code/Reformat code...` - i.e. it formats the files being committed according to your project Code Style preferences (`Settings (Preferences) | Editor | Code Style`).

`Rearrange Code` command sorts/groups statements in your files (same as `Code/Rearrange Code`) according to arrangement preferences, if any (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/code-style-php.html?from=old_help#d468513e1246).